# How to get an existing video thumbnail image from MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to get a thumbnail image for a video that I've just chosen (or recorded) via the UIImagePickerController. In my picker's FinishedPickingMedia method, I get what I believe to be the path to the video file and use it to save the recording to album. The newly recorded video does indeed appear in my album. Now to get the thumbnail…

I've tried using the ALAssetsLibrary in a couple ways. First, I've enumerated all the videos and tried to find a match from the asset's UtiToUrlDictionary.Values[0] value, which reveals its file path. No entries matched the path I obtained from the FinishedPickingMedia method's mediaUrlKey.

My second attempt was to use the ALAssetsLibrary's AssetForUrl() method. Again, I tried my FinishedPickingMedia method's mediaUrlKey, but there was no match.

The UIImagePickerController -> FinishedPickingMedia -> mediaUrlKey returns a path of:

```
file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/73037738-C060-4DE6-A1CA-698E6BE083F2/tmp//trim.iRBwWw.MOV
```

After painful digging and inspecting every video in my library, it the same video's path from the ALAssetsLibrary is:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.MOV?id=B073FCF6-83ED-436B-AFD8-42D0A6C70FC6&ext=MOV
```

Why are the video paths different between UIIMagePickerController and ALAssetsLibrary? How can I get ALAssetsLibrary to return the same video picked from UIImagePickerController?

[code for the picker]

```
public override void FinishedPickingMedia (UIImagePickerController picker, NSDictionary info)
{
    var mediaUrlKey = new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL");
    var mediaPath = (NSUrl) info.ObjectForKey(mediaUrlKey);


    if( recordView.RecordVideo )
    {
        if(mediaPath != null)
        {
            if(UIVideo.IsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(mediaPath.Path))
            {
                UIVideo.SaveToPhotosAlbum(mediaPath.Path, SaveToPhotosAlbumResults);
            }
            else
            {
                using (var alert = new UIAlertView("Problem Encountered", 
                "Unable to save this recording.", null, "Ok!", null))
                {
                    alert.Show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        recordView.VideoFileLocation = mediaPath;
        //ALAssetsLibrary library = new ALAssetsLibrary();
        //library.AssetForUrl( mediaPath, GetAssetResult, GetAssetError );
    }

    recordView.VideoFileLocation = mediaPath;

    Console.WriteLine("***" + recordView.VideoFileLocation.ToString()+ "***");

    recordView.ShowUploadButton();
    recordView.SetThumbnailImage();

    picker.DismissModalViewControllerAnimated(true);
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think may be it is too late but the following code work as of now

```
public static UIImage GenerateImage(NSUrl videoUrl)
{
   var asset = AVAsset.FromUrl(videoUrl);
   var imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator.FromAsset(asset);
   imageGenerator.AppliesPreferredTrackTransform = true;

   var actualTime = asset.Duration;
   CoreMedia.CMTime cmTime = new CoreMedia.CMTime(1, 60);

   NSError error;
   var imageRef = imageGenerator.CopyCGImageAtTime(cmTime, out actualTime, out error);

   if (imageRef == null)
       return null;

   var image = UIImage.FromImage(imageRef);

   return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the section `Can I Get To The Original File Representing This Image on the Disk` [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get a thumbnail within the picker delegate:

```
NSUrl data = new NSUrl(info.ObjectForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL")).ToString());

                //get the video thumbnail

                MPMoviePlayerController movie = new MPMoviePlayerController(data);
                movie.Stop();
                UIImage videoThumbnail = movie.ThumbnailImageAt(0.0,MPMovieTimeOption.NearestKeyFrame);
                movie.Stop();
```